# Talkies, Motion Pictures, Movies, Films and 3D

Tags: etymology, american-english, british-english

The term [talkies](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=talkie&allowed_in_frame=0), i.e. *talking pictures*, I was surprised to learn was not coined in 1927 after the release of *The Jazz Singer*, but in 1913. The term is now obsolete whereas *[motion picture](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=motion%20picture&searchmode=none)*, meaning *moving pictures* on a screen, has existed since 1896, although it's become more dated. [Movie](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=movie&allowed_in_frame=0), its shortened and more modern version, dated possibly from 1908, is still very much in vogue in the US.

The  Online Etymology Dictionary says that [*film*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/film) (the more popular BrEng equivalent for *movie*) was

> First used of "motion pictures" in 1905.

British speakers will say:

> 1. Have you seen the new James Bond film?
> 2. We watched a film about prison life.
> 3. The film was made on location in India.

American speakers, if I'm not mistaken, will use *film* in sentence number two, and *movie* in the others. *Movie* is connected more with entertainment, whereas *film* is considered more of an art form, an  undergraduate will take *Film & Media Studies*, not *Movies & Media Studies*.

My questions:

- I'd like to know when the term *talkies* as in "talking pictures" died out. When was it no longer considered a novelty and people reverted back to saying *motion pictures*/*movies*?
- Why the term, film, was adopted by British speakers and most European countries when *motion pictures* is arguably the authentic expression and therefore, the more accurate term.
- Lastly, which term is more common: *3D film* or *3D movie*? (The latter does sound odd to my ears.)

Comment: I don't know the answers to your questions, but I'll venture another synonym for you: *picture*.

Comment: @tobyink  That's a shorter version for "motion picture" which I'd guess postdates it.

Comment: If a moving picture is a "movie" and a moving picture with sound is a "talkie", can I propose we call moving pictures with 3 dimensions "depthies"?

Comment: Not very catchy though, is it? I'd go for "3dies" or "3dees"

Comment: I almost always hear 3D movie in the US and film when in France or the UK - 3D film sounds odd to me.  In the US when we hear film, it means that the movie is foreign or some fancy-artsy type.  I for one won't go see a film unless it is foreign.

Comment: @RyeBread is yours a typical American viewpoint, do you think? What about the *movie industry*, is the term, film, ever used?

Comment: Typical American, pretty sure.  Typical ELU, not sure at all.  Also film industry is used much more and around 50/50 with movie in that context.  Like I mentioned before the word "film" is fancier here and the people in the industry like the fancy label.  We make films not movies.

Comment: Shouldn't this be three separate questions?

Comment: I agree with Chris. Can you split this up into three separate questions so all three portions can get the coverage they deserve?

Comment: Btw, "We watched a movie about prison life" is much more common in the US. The only people who regularly use "film" in the US are film aficionados (and those in the film industry).

Comment: **motion picture** is dated? It's the current term!

Comment: @RyeBread - There's little more foreign to the average American than how Hollywood thinks.

Comment: Film, or more properly Feeelm, is the pretentious term often used in college courses.

Comment: @MrHen perhaps the second question deserves its own space, but considering also the low view counts, I'm not entirely convinced it would attract an/any answer(s).

Comment: @Oldcat I disagree, *motion picture* has been replaced by *movie* and *film*. It's not obsolete, by any means but it does have a nostalgic, retro quality to it, which might put off movie goers. It's not an expression I ever used or heard said in the UK.

Comment: "Motion picture" very much has a dated feel in the US as well.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It is still the formal term. The "Academy" that issues Oscars is the "Academy of Motion Picture Arts and Science".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure when the term "talkie" in the context of "motion picture" died out, but I have heard of the term "talkie" being used for movies that have very little action and mostly dialogue. In this context, I have heard the movie "Interview With a Vampire" being described as a "talkie".

I think the reason "Motion Picture" would be more accurate than "Film" is because the term "Film" can also refer to still pictures, like "film in the camera".

As for 3D, I have heard the term "3D Movie" used a lot here in the United States. I haven't met anyone who says "3D Film".

Comment: One word meaning two things does not make the word less accurate. :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in AE, "movie" and "film" can have different connotations, depicting the quality:

- Film: Citizen Kane
- Movie: Jennifer's Body

Film is more a work of art, whereas movie is tripe sold to the lowest common denominator of moviegoers (of course, I've never heard the term "filmgoers").

Comment: Filmgoers is used by certain movie critics and reviewers. The film/movie distinction you note is mostly unfounded. The only people I know who try to make that distinction are self-admitted film snobs. If you were to correct anyone using a term with this definition it would be considered rather insulting.

Comment: Different people vary in where they draw the line.  Some, for example, use the term "movie" for moving images recorded in any medium, while reserving the term "film" for moving pictures photographically rendered on a strip of celluloid, acetate, polyester, or other similar medium.